# kable produces malformed reference links within lapply function in blogdown

Tags: r, knitr, blogdown

I am using blogdown to to create a blogpost that has a series of tables. Creating a single table using the `kable` function works fine. If you do

```r
blogdown::new_site()
blogdown::new_post("test", ext = ".rmd")
```

A new rmd file will be created within the `content/post` directory of the project. If you open that file and create a single table by doing

````
```{r test1}
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)

data.frame(a= c(1,2,3)) %>% kable(caption = 'test',format = 'html')

```
````

A correctly formatted table will be generated. The caption will read "
Table 1: test" If you look at the code of the generated site, the caption will look like this.

```html
<caption>
<span id="tab:test1">Table 1: </span>test
</caption>
```

Ideally I don't have any desire to label the table as `Table 1` in the first place but that is another question. If formatting of captions by kable can be disabled entirely, I'd also be happy.

However if I use lapply to generate 2 tables instead

````
```{r test2}

lapply(1:2,function(x){
    data.frame(a= c(1,2,3)) %>% kable(caption = 'test2',format = 'html') %>% HTML()
}) -> tables

tables[[1]]

tables[[2]]

```
````

The captions will have the prefix `\#tab:test2`. If you look at the caption of these tables, you'll see

```html
<caption>(\#tab:test2)test2</caption>
```

**The question is**, why `kable` behaves differently when its called from a `lapply` compared to its behaviour outside? Note that both of these behaviours are different that its behaviour when simply knitting the file as an `html_document`.

I did some digging into the `kable`'s code and found that the caption link is created by the `knitr:::create_label` function. Looking into this function, I saw the part that is responsible for the wrong behaviour seen with the multiple tables.

```r
if (isTRUE(opts_knit$get("bookdown.internal.label"))) {
    lab1 = "(\\#"
    lab2 = ")"
}
```

I could not find the code, responsible for the "correct" behaviour with the single table but it seems like knitr internal options are responsible.

Ultimately the behaviour that I want is simply

```html
<caption>test</caption>
```

which is the behaviour when simply knitting an html document. But I am yet to find a way to set the relevant knitr options and why are they different within the same document.

Edit: Further examination suggests that the issue isn't lapply specific. It can be replicated using a for loop or even `{` by itself. A complete post with all the problematic examples can be acquired from [this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1669) issue on knitr's github page. [This](https://github.com/oganm/bgtest) github repo includes the basic blogdown site that replicates the issue

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want "Table 1" in "Table 1 caption blablabla", right?

Comment: That is correct. But I am more surprised by (and also want to get rid of) the `<caption>(\#tab:test2)test2</caption>` style tags which causes the label to appear as text

Comment: You can also see [this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1669) issue for an example file that demonstrates all problematic cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the responsible party is not the `lapply` call but the `HTML` call at the end. It seems like the regular process by `knitr` in `blogdown` and `bookdown` is to have a temporary marker for the table references in the form of `(\#tab:label)` and replace it with the appropriate syntax later in the processing.

I was using the HTML call to be able to use the `tags` object in shiny/htmltools to bind the tables together. This approach seems to make the process of replacing the temporary marker impossible for reasons outside my understanding. For my own purposes I was able to remove the temporary marker all together to get rid of both malformed captions and the working-as-intended table numbers by doing

```r
remove_table_numbers = function(table){
  old_attributes = attributes(table)
  table %<>% as.character() %>% gsub("\\(\\\\#tab:.*?\\)","",.)
  attributes(table) = old_attributes
  return(table)
}

data.frame(a= c(1,2,3)) %>% kable(caption = 'test',format = 'html') %>% remove_table_numbers
```

This question still would benefit from a proper explanation of the reference link placement process and if its possible to apply it to tables in `HTML` calls as well. But for know this solves my issue. I'll gladly switch the accepted answer if a more complete explanation appears